# Write to an existing topic with ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have three Kafka topics: `entity.created`, `entity.deleted`, `entity.attribute`. They all have some entity ID as the message key and a Protobuf message value.

I'm trying to use ksqlDB to aggregate messages from the first two topics and produce messages to the third one:

```sql
-- TODO: this might be possible to do with just one table

CREATE TABLE apples_created AS
  SELECT references->basket_id, count(1) AS count
  FROM entity_created
  WHERE type = 'APPLE'
  GROUP BY references->basket_id
  EMIT CHANGES;

CREATE TABLE apples_deleted AS
  SELECT references->basket_id, count(1) AS count
  FROM entity_deleted
  WHERE type = 'APPLE'
  GROUP BY references->basket_id
  EMIT CHANGES;

CREATE TABLE apples_any AS
  SELECT apples_created.basket_id AS basket_id, apples_deleted.count IS NULL OR apples_created.count > apples_deleted.count AS has_apples
  FROM apples_created
  LEFT JOIN apples_deleted ON apples_created.apple_id = apples_deleted.apple_id
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

However, I have found no way to get the output of `apples_any` to my `entity.attribute` topic. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE attr_testing WITH (kafka_topic = 'entity.attribute') AS
  SELECT basket_id, 'BASKET' AS type, 'hasApples' AS name, CASE WHEN has_apples THEN 'true' ELSE '' END AS value
  FROM apples_any
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

fails, because it tries to register its own schema for the existing topic:

```
Could not register schema for topic: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "entity.attribute-value"; error code: 409
```

I will have multiple Kafka producers writing to `entity.attribute` and want ksqlDB to be just one of them. Is writing to an existing topic possible with ksqlDB? If not, I imagine I need a way to copy messages from `apples_any` (the underlying topic) to `entity.attribute`. What would be the preferred solution in the Kafka ecosystem?

I'm using ksqlDB 0.17.0.

Edit:

This is the value schema used by the `entity.attribute` topic:

```
message EntityAttribute {
  EntityType type = 2;
  string name = 3;
  string value = 4;
}

enum EntityType {
  APPLE = 0;
  BASKET = 1;
}
```

Edit 2:

The error in ksqlDB logs I get when I try to create that `attr_testing` table is:

```
WARN Found incompatible change: Difference{fullPath='#/EntityAttribute', type=MESSAGE_REMOVED} (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.protobuf.ProtobufSchema)
```

If I understand correctly, ksqlDB is trying to create a completely new schema, with a different message name. This leads me to believe that whatever schema I use, ksqlDB will ignore it. Also, I have no idea how I could tell ksqlDB to create an enum field (`EntityType`) instead of a string. That's why I feel like producing to an existing topic is not a ksqlDB's use case...

Comment: If you create a new stream `AS SELECT` from another stream, then it should create another topic

Comment: Your error isn't saying that producing isn't possible at all, it's telling you that your selected columns don't match the schema for `entity.attribute-value`... Would you mind sharing what that schema is?

Comment: "If you create a new stream AS SELECT from another stream, then it should create another topic " That's the thing. I don't want to create another topic, I want to write to an existing topic.

"Your error isn't saying that producing isn't possible at al [...]" Yes, if I specify a different kafka_topic and let ksqldb create it, everything works. But my goal is to produce to an existing topic.

Comment: Can you also show the schema of `apples_any`? I think the problem might be that when you have `AS SELECT basket_id`, it is treating that as part of the value

Comment: The schema of `apples_any` is whatever ksqlDB creates automatically. I don't think it's treated as a value. In fact I noticed that the first column is normally stored in the message key.

But disregarding the details, my main question is: can ksqlDB produce to an existing topic or is that not a use case? If it is, I'd appreciate some links/docs, as I haven't been able to find much myself.

Comment: It can. And it is trying to. The problem is that the Protobuf schema generated by your query isn't backwards compatible with what's currently in the registry

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for looking into this, and sorry for the delay - I was busy with other tasks. I added the error logged by ksqlDB and explained why I feel like I'm trying to do something that ksqlDB is not meant (or not ready) to do.